# error android SDK in class R

Tags: android, sdk

I update my SDK, and now it is giving error in my whole project. Says that there is a class named R, which is where the layout call.

this with error in the line

```
import br.com.projeto_tcc.R;
```

Comment: Remove that line and try to clean and re-build the project.

Comment: try Projet -> clean
otherwise, relaunch eclipse

Answer (score 0):

R is the automatically generated with references to all your resources. It is used very frequently in android, so when it 'disappears', it seems to cause an error throughout the whole project.

As has been mentioned in comments above, a rebuild will sometimes solve the issue. However, if the issue is still persisting and the compiler is still unable to find the class 'R', then you need to start looking at your xml files (layouts, menus, etc).

When there is a syntax error in an android XML file, the error notification is not displayed as prominently as it is for errors in Java files (if you are using Eclipse with ADT plugin, as most android devs do). As such, it is pretty easy to miss a typo or other syntax error in one of these files unless you go through and look in each individual one (or check the errors tab in the window at the bottom of your screen if using eclipse/adt).

Syntax errors in these XML files prevent the generation of the R class; therefore, when the java compiler is looking at the references you make to the R class (for example, R.layout.foo or R.id.bar), it cannot find the class, and highlights those lines of code as errors.

So, make sure that your XML files are all well-formed, because this is a fairly common issue, especially if you are just learning your way around adt.

Comment: It was working before I update the folder after gen\com\test\project with the R class missing.

Comment: Well you never _want_ to have your R class missing. Did you check the xml files?